# Iterating through JSON object item values in Redshift

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-redshift

We have a json object as one of our columns in the database. I can reach the values one by one with json_extract_path_text, but I could not figure out a way to iterate through all values to summarize all value (value1, value2, value1, value2, value3) items.

```
select  json_extract_path_text('{"test_0":{"value1":6050,"value2":3000},"test_1":{"value1":6000,"value2":200,"value3":50}}','test_0', 'value1')
```

Comment: you will need a udf for this. are you able/allowed to create and use plpythonu UDF functions? see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-security-and-privileges.html

Comment: @JonScott Yes I can use them. I will try to implement an UDF. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: UDF would be best but in a pinch, if there is a fixed number of columns, you could "union all" them together and sum them based on whatever other columns are there.